# How to expand a child element without affecting the parent element?

Tags: html, css

I want that when I hover over a child class, it doesn't affect the overflow of the parent. My expectation is to remove the line `position: relative;` in the parent, but this doesn't work correctly when I have many nested positions.

```css
.parent-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  &:hover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `overflow: visible` on the parent?

Comment: Does the parent still need to support overflow at all? If not, you could just set `overflow: hidden` on the parent. (Edit: Or `visible` as mentioned above, depending on your desired result)

Comment: Ahh, wait, I think I got it. You have many children and WANT there to be a scrollbar for the parent. However, when someone hovers over a child, that child should expand and overflow the parent while leaving all other children (and the scrollbars) intact. I'm afraid this is not possible with pure CSS. I suggest involving Javascript. When someone is hovering over a child, you create a clone of it which is NOT a child of the parent anymore, and then position it carefully to create an illusion that the original child has expanded.

Comment: @Vilx- it sound good, i'll try thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution

```css
.parent-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  /* Add smooth transition for height changes */
}

.container:hover .child {
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Position the expanding child at the bottom of the container */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what I expected. I want the child should expand and overflow the parent while leaving all other children (and the scrollbars) intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve that without `position: relative`. It helps to recognize where your element's absolute position is. Otherwise, your elements will use the position (0,0) by default.

If you want to have the same design but with a slightly different approach. You can try below solution with another wrapper element.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.parent-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  &:hover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent-1">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```